# Not able to pass repeater Container.ItemIndex to javascript function as an argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, repeater

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function EnableDisablePkgInclusionDropDown(val) {

        alert("RowIndex: " + val);        
        var repeater = document.getElementById('<%= pnlrptPckgInclusions.ClientID %>');
        var dropdowns = repeater.getElementsByTagName('select');
        dropdowns[val].disabled = true;
        dropdowns[val].selectedIndex = "0";
}
</Script>

    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptPckgInclusions">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                                        <tr>

                                            <td align="left" style="width: 20%; text-align: left">
                                                Parent MarkUp
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                                        <tr>                                            

                                            <td align="center" style="width: 20%;">
                                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkApplyParentMarkUp" OnClick="javascript:EnableDisablePkgInclusionDropDown(<%# Container.ItemIndex %>);"/>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

I am trying to pass container.ItemIndex as an argument to javascript function on checkbox OnClick event to enable/disable few controls.But Its not showing the value in Javascript function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all be careful in components namings inside your JS function (**pnlrpt**PckgInclusions != **rpt**PckgInclusions)

After this change you **OnClick** handler to this

```
OnClick='<%# "javascript:EnableDisablePkgInclusionDropDown(" + Container.ItemIndex + ")" %>'
```

It should help. Have a nice day !

Comment: getting below error:                                                                          Conversion from string "javascript:EnableDisablePkgInclu" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: Please, check your code carefully. It works fine in my VS project. You shouldn't get a compilation error. Only js error should be thrown here   "var dropdowns = repeater.getElementsByTagName('select');" because you don't have select element inside repeater

Comment: its giving me runtime error not compiled time.In my actual code,there is a drop down inside repeater.I tried passing an integer hard coded value and it was working fine. I think there is a problem in passing index as an argument.

Comment: Extend your question and show me where are you passing index to the select

Comment: My purpose is to access repeater's particular row based on check box checked event that resides in repeater.So I was trying to achieve that by passing container.ItemIndex property.

Comment: @dimnoser : i was getting that error due to '+' sign since i m using Vb language :)  which i rectified by replacing '+' with '&'.But how can i pass that checkbox using this keyword?

Comment: how to pass plain text in above javascript fuction as an 2nd argument?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest my way.
Just add an attribute say name='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' in the markup.
For example,

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
       <tr>                                            
       <td align="center" style="width: 20%;">
           <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkFoo" OnClick="Test(this)" name='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'/>
       </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Now, in the javascript method Test(this), you can get the repeater row index using 'this.name'.

Alternatively, if you observe the generated markup html, you will find the ID of the checkbox is generated as something 'ConetentPlaceholder1_rptTest_chkFoo_0.
You can split this id in javascript method to get the repeater row index.